# Saving and retrieving Images from MySQL DB using VB.net, PHP and Java

Tags: php, mysql, .net, binary-data

I have a VB.net application that can store and retrieve images from my database. It all works.

I then made an Android app (in Java) that can run on the phone to send pictures to the same database using a PHP script. This way, users do not have to take pictures and then download them to the PC first.
My problem comes when trying to open the pictures stored with PHP...

This is how I do it in vb:

```vb
Public Function updateDropPics(iDrop As String, fImg As Image, sType As String, sDate As String)
    Dim arrImage() As Byte
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand
    Dim Sql As String = ""
    Try
        Dim mstreamF As New System.IO.MemoryStream()

        fImg.Save(mstreamF, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
        arrImage = mstreamF.GetBuffer()
        mstreamF.Close()

        Sql = "UPDATE  photos SET Picture_Data= @fImg, Date_Added = @Date 
               WHERE Drop_ID = @iDrop"

        cmd.Connection = MySqlConn
        cmd.CommandText = Sql
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@iDrop", iDrop)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fImg", arrImage)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", sDate)

        Dim r As Integer
        r = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        If r > 0 Then
            'MsgBox("Record has been Saved!")
        Else
            MsgBox("No record has been saved!")
        End If
        cmd.Parameters.Clear()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try

    Return 0
End Function
```

To show the image, I run a `SELECT` statement and then load the data into and image:

```vb
Dim arrImage() As Byte
arrImage = pTable.Rows(0).Item("Picture_Data")
Dim mstream As New System.IO.MemoryStream(arrImage)
OriginalPreviewImage = Image.FromStream(mstream)
```

As I said this works great.

In the Android app I send the image to a PHP script and store it in the database like so:

```php
// Attempt 1: Convert to base64 
$image_base64 = base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']) );
$image = 'data:image/'.$imageFileType.';base64,'.$image_base64;

//Attempt 2: use the received file directly
//$image = file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']) ;
//Attempt 3: Save thefiletodisk then to db
//$image = file_get_contents($file_path) ;

$query = "INSERT INTO Photos(Picture_Data) values('".$image."')";
mysqli_query($con,$query);

// Upload file
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],$upload_path.$name.$imageFileType);
```

(I first check if the record exist then either update or insert as required. code not shown). When I googled it everyone said use base64, but when the error showed up I realised that I am not doing this in VB, so I tied a few other options. The records are created in the database and I know the picture uploads cause I'm also saving it to a folder on the server for now as a test.
When I run the VB app I get the following error when trying to display the picture:

> Parameter not valid

in this line:

```vb
OriginalPreviewImage = Image.FromStream(mstream)
```

It appears my VB application does not like the data I put in with PHP.
`Image.FromStream` cannot open the PHP data.
How do I get PHP to save the same format into the DB as VB?

Any help appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like I solved my own problem.

Changed my PHP code to the following:

```php
$stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO photos (Picture_Data, Drop_ID,  File_Path) VALUES(?,?,?)");
$null = NULL;
$stmt->bind_param("bis", $null, $dropId, $file_path);
$stmt->send_long_data(0, file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
$stmt->execute();

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],$file_path);
```

`send_long_data` did the trick.